# Firestore multiple orderBy (composite index) can't find some results

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a query that I run over multiple data types. One of the collections stopped returning results after I added `orderBy`s.

```
getEntitiesOfType(entityType: EntityType): Observable<StructuralEntity[]> {
    const collection = this.findCollection(entityType);

    const entities$ = this.afs
      .collection(collection, (ref) =>
        ref.orderBy('disabled').orderBy('title').orderBy('id') // Here is the issue
      )
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((docs) =>
          docs.map((dca) => {
            const data = dca.payload.doc.data() as StructuralEntity;
            return {
              id: dca.payload.doc.id,
              title: data.title,
              name: data.name,
              type: data.type,
              icon: data.icon,
              model: data.model,
              context: data.context,
              disabled: data.disabled,
            } as StructuralEntity;
          })
        )
      );

    return entities$;
  }
```

I had to order some collection by `disabled` and `title`, the collection that stopped returning results doesn't have those fields so I suppose that is why it doesn't return anything anymore. I've added field `id` to the composite index, which it certainly has, hoping it would work again. It does not.

Why does Firestore not return anything for this index?

| disabled | title | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| undefined | undefined | "1" |
| undefined | undefined | "2" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore only includes documents in an index that have a value for the fields in that index.

If a document doesn't have a value for the `disabled` field, it won't exist in the composite index, and thus can never be returned from a query that uses that index.

If you want such documents to be returned, you'll have to add the new field to the documents with some default value.

Comment: I thought one of the points of having a document database was that docs can have different shapes. This is really counter intuitive to me. Good to know though.